# has_term() does not return when term is assigned post?

Tags: terms

Ok, I have an archive loop.

In this loop I have this...

```
<?php if ( has_term('race') ) { ?>
   <strong class="archive-event"><?php the_title($event); ?></strong>
<?php } ?>
```

But it does no show whats anything!?

And I have these terms assigned to the post...

- Tax: report-type Term: race
- Tax: season-year Term: motogp-2013

My question is why does this not return nothing? Or what function should I be using to display something (in the loop) if the post has the term assigned to it?

Weirdly this works...

```
<?php if ( has_term('race', 'report-type', $post->ID )) { ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that [the Codex information for `has_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) is incorrect:

```
<?php has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post ) ?>
```

And for the `$taxonomy` parameter:

> $taxonomy (string) 
>   (optional) Taxonomy name 
>   Default: ''

But if you look at [the source for `has_term()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src//wp-includes/category-template.php#L1204):

```
$r = is_object_in_term( $post->ID, $taxonomy, $term );
```

So, `$taxonomy` is passed to [`is_object_in_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_object_in_term):

```
<?php is_object_in_term( $object_id, $taxonomy, $terms = null ) ?>
```

Which says for the `$taxonomy` parameter:

> $taxonomy (string) 
>   (required) A single taxonomy name. 
>   Default: None

(A look at [source for `is_object_in_term()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L3329) confirms that the `$taxonomy` parameter is required, and will result in returning `false` if not passed.)

So, it would appear that failing to pass `$taxonomy` to `has_term()` will result in `has_term()` returning `false`.

It appears that the source inline docs have been updated accordingly:

```
* @param string|int|array $term Optional. The term name/term_id/slug or array of them to check for.
* @param string $taxonomy Taxonomy name
* @param int|object $post Optional. Post to check instead of the current post.
* @return bool True if the current post has any of the given tags (or any tag, if no tag specified).
```

The `$taxonomy` parameter is no longer listed as `Optional`.

Comment: Note: I've updated the Codex entry for `has_term()` accordingly.

Comment: The new code reference has this wrong as well.