# Order posts with custom taxonomy array

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, terms, array, order

I am trying to make my loop go through the posts that are associated with these terms. Currently nothing is being output.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'staff',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'staff',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array(
                                    'editor-in-chief',
                                    'managing-editor',
                                    'fiction-editor',
                                    'poetry-editor',
                                    'nonfiction-editor',
                                    'production-manager'
                                )
                )
            )
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        ?>

                    <div class="loop four columns">
                        <div class="column-nest">
                            <h5 class="staff-title big-top-space"><?php the_field('staff_title'); ?></h5>
                            <h6 class="staff-name  bottom-space"><?php the_field('staff_member_name'); ?></h6>              
                        </div> <!-- column-nest -->
                        <figure class="staff-photo-border">
                            <img class="column-nest" src="<?php the_field('staff_member_photo'); ?>" alt="photo of <?php the_field('staff_member_name'); ?>" />
                        </figure> <!-- staff-photo-border -->
                    </div> <!-- loop four columns -->


        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `has_term()` requires the name of the **taxonomy** as a parameter.

References:

- [has_term() does not return when term is assigned post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128892/has-term-does-not-return-when-term-is-assigned-post)
- [Function Reference/has term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the loop for terms. Use tax_query instead. Here is the codex link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

You arguments should be

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'staff',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_slug',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array(
                                'editor-in-chief',
                                'managing-editor',
                                'fiction-editor',
                                'poetry-editor',
                                'nonfiction-editor',
                                'production-manager'
                            )
            )
        )
);
```

Change "taxonomy_slug" to the right slug.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey Jeff thanks for the help! I made some edits see above original post to see where I am hung up.

Comment: Are you sure the taxonomy slug is the same as the post type? Thanks